# Selenium being unresponsive on a page with alerts

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a minimal example for which Chrome driver is being unresponsive.

**alert.html:**

```html
<html>
        <body>
            <a href="test_alert.html" target="_blank" id="test">Visit Alert test!</a>
        </body>
</html>
```

**test_alert.html:**

```html
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Hello world");
    </script>
</html>
```

I wrote a Python-based Selenium script to click on the  link and am then trying to accept the alert. But, after the click on  link, Chrome driver is not responding.

Here's the Python script that produces this problem:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

SHORT_PAUSE = 5
capabilities = {
  'chromeOptions': {
    'androidPackage': 'org.chromium.chrome',
  }
}
driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:9515', capabilities)
url = "http://10.0.0.173:8888/alert.html"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(SHORT_PAUSE)


element = driver.find_element_by_id("test")
element.click()
print "done clicking"

# Usually prints: "[u'CDwindow-0', u'CDwindow-1']" 
print driver.window_handles
time.sleep(SHORT_PAUSE)
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

# Selenium is unresponsive after this and 
# never prints the below line
print "current url:", driver.current_url
alert = driver.switch_to.alert
print "switched to alert. Text:", alert.text
alert.accept()
print "Accepted modal dialog...."
```

**Version information:**

- Python: 2.7.6
- Selenium: 3.4.2
- Chrome driver: 2.29
- Chrome version: 58.0.3029.83 (on Android 7.1.1 connected via USB)
- Host machine: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Comment: You might want to include the Python script.

Comment: @Phani Can you consider to share your work please? Thanks

Comment: @Paul I have included the Python script that produces the problem.

Comment: Any reason for the down vote? I've been struggling with this for the past couple of days. I will be happy to provide any information you might need.

Comment: Attribute `target="_blank"` means that link should be opened in new window/tab, so you should switch to new window before switching to alert.

Comment: @Andersson I have done that but the result is the same. I included the lines that do that as well for your reference. While the switch to the new window seems to happen, the alert is not getting accepted after that. Even the line, that says 'current url' isn't getting printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is an existing Chromedriver bug:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=833

Until the issue is fixed, my work around for this is to use `adb shell` commands to send key board inputs for dealing with alerts whenever I anticipate an alert window to pop up.

```
adb shell input keyevent 61 #Tab key for focus
adb shell input keyevent 66 #Enter key to deal with the alert
```

After dismissing the alert, chromedriver seems to work normally again.

**Note:** If you are using a Linux system, you can use `xdotool` instead.